# Easy Way To Filter Logger Console Output in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

I have named all my loggers through the program.  What I would like to do is be be able to filter the console logging output by logger name(s) in Pycharm.  Can this be done without editing the log configurations file?

Comment: When you say loggers, are you talking about the Python `logging` library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)? Please give an example what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes.  The logging library.  In the code I have loggers tagged with the logger_name.  I would like to be able to filter all other loggers except ones with specified names while debugging.  It would also be nice to be able to filter based on debug, info, error on the fly without having to change the logger level setting.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter output in PyCharm's Console window using [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console) plugin.

Also, if you want better support for `logging` standard module in PyCharm then please vote for issue [PY-8408](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8408) – *logging module integration into PyCharm*