# How to add key word to filter console output in PyCharm?

Tags: logging, filter, pycharm

I know there have some similar questions asked ([Easy Way To Filter Logger Console Output in Pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480774/easy-way-to-filter-logger-console-output-in-pycharm)). But it's different. I want to know how to filter the log output from the Pycharm GUI after program is running instead of setting logging from code. After program started from Pycharm IDE, we could see the log message from "Debug console" tab, the message is too much, i only want to see the logs by some key words dynamic for temporary.(for example, like Android Studio, Eclipse ...). Too many topics talked how to set the logging output from code by logging lib, it's different requirement.
Thanks

Comment: here is a capture of my debug console: https://ibb.co/fXWwSv . I know we could search keyword from the window, but it's just highlight the log instead of filter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can filter output in Console window with [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console) plugin.